# Elasticsearch Geo shape search against nested documents

Tags: nested, elasticsearch, geojson, geo

I would like to be able to search against documents using a `geo_shape` filter (where the geojson is a nested subdocument) and only retrieve the 1 sub document that matched the geographical filter (not the whole document). I think the docs (specifically nested object type and nested query/filter docs) state this is possible using join:false. For some reason I can't get it to work though and I'm convinced it's a user error or lack of understanding.

On ES 90.5 and below is a worked example.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

## Clear the deck and create a new index

```
curl -XDELETE http://es_server.com:9200/test

{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}

curl -XPUT  http://es_server.com:9200/test

{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
```

## Set a new mapping for the `testtype`

```
curl -XPUT http://es_server.com:9200/test/testtype/_mapping -d '{
  "testtype": {
    "properties": {
      "entities": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "geometry": {
            "tree": "quadtree",
            "type": "geo_shape",
            "precision": "10m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
```

## Index a new document

```
curl -XPUT http://es_server.com:9200/test/testtype/doc1 -d '{
  "id": "doc1",
  "entities": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          0.0,
          0.0
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          180.0,
          90.0
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

## Query WITH join:false

```
curl -XGET http://es_server.com:9200/test/testtype/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "entities",
          "join": false,
          "filter": {
            "geo_shape": {
              "entities.geometry": {
                "shape": {
                  "type": "envelope",
                  "coordinates": [
                    [
                      -10.0,
                      10.0
                    ],
                    [
                      10.0,
                      -10.0
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

## Query WITHOUT join:false

```
curl -XGET http://es_server.com:9200/test/testtype/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "entities",
          "filter": {
            "geo_shape": {
              "entities.geometry": {
                "shape": {
                  "type": "envelope",
                  "coordinates": [
                    [
                      -10.0,
                      10.0
                    ],
                    [
                      10.0,
                      -10.0
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "testtype",
        "_id": "doc1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "doc1",
          "entities": [
            {
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                  0.0,
                  0.0
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                  180.0,
                  90.0
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```